# Find $F'(t)$, where F is an integral

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I need to find $F'(t)$, where $F(t)=\int_{[0,t]^2}e^{\frac{tx}{y^2}}dxdy$.

My first approach:

Let's observe that $\int e^{\frac{tx}{y^2}}dx=\frac{y^2}{t}e^{\frac{tx}{y^2}}+C$.

So I get: $$F(t)=\int_{[0,t]^2}e^{\frac{tx}{y^2}}dxdy=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{y^2}{t}e^{\frac{t^2}{y^2}}-\frac{y^2}{t}dy$$

But now the integral isn't so easy. Has anybody got any ideas? Is there a better way to find the derviative of $F$ or do I need to calculate it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait, $F(t)$ is divergent. By a change of variable, $F(t) = t^2 F(1)$, and $F(1)$ is divergent since $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 e^{\frac{x}{y^2}}\, dx\, dy = \int_0^1 y^2(e^{\frac{1}{y^2}} - 1)\, dy,$$

which is divergent. Indeed, for all $x\ge 0$, $e^x - 1 = \int_0^x e^t\, dt \ge \int_0^x 1\, dt = x$. Hence, for all $x\ge 0$, $e^x - 1 \ge \int_0^x t\, dt = \frac{x^2}{2}$. In particular, $e^{1/y^2} - 1 \ge \frac{1}{2y^4}$ for all $y > 0$. So $y^2(e^{1/y^2} - 1) \ge \frac{1}{2y^2}$ for all $y > 0$. Since $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2y^2}\, dy$ is divergent, by the comparison test for integrals, $\int_0^1 y^2(e^{1/y^2} - 1)\, dy$ is divergent.

Comment: How do you find the change of variable?

Comment: Set $u = \frac{x}{t}$ and $v = \frac{y}{t}$.

Comment: Why is the last integral divergent?

Comment: It's because $\int_0^1 y^2 e^{1/y^2}\, dy$ is divergent. Can you see why?

Comment: Nope. I've written it down, I try to do some kind of substitution, but nothing works so far.

Comment: @Mark I hope this is made clear in my edit. :-)

Comment: Yes. Thank you a lot. ;)